# is there a way to use mysql "into outfile" to generate one file per row? and name of the file should be id of the row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to dump some data from a table to text files. so i want to pick the "contnet" column and put in a text file with name of the text fiel as ID_OF_THAT_ROW + '.txt'?

Regards,

Comment: ... Why do you want that?

Comment: You'll probably need to program that yourself...

Comment: I have data in a table and I need to export that data to txt files. and the way I want is that the "content" column in each row should be stored in a separate file. I dont have to use Id in the file name, all i need is I need to create different files and using id is kind of natural to use in file name.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do 
    mysql -pxxx -uxxx -e "select * from tbl where id = 2" > /tmp/test.txt

Now using MS-excel I make it to desired csv or so

Comment: where xx =yz is fine and work, but I need to dump all rows in separate files.

Comment: Why do you want to do everything in mysql? You can always "split" to break it into pieces in Linux. You can formulate a query which creates queries to spit out each row and run the query etc.